# How to replace default image when user selected image?

Tags: java, image, uiimageview

I have one default image and I want to replace the image when the user or the program already selected an image. I have only the basic image reader for displaying the default image.

```
private static void loadImage()throws Exception{
    File image2 = new File("...Example\\blackimage.jpg");
    bi = ImageIO.read(image2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override methods so

```
private static void loadImage(String imagePath) throws Exception {
  File image2 = new File(imagePath);
  bi = ImageIO.read(image2);
}

private static void loadImage() throws Exception {
  loadImage("...Example\\blackimage.jpg");
}
```

This would give you two methods, one to call if you have a image in mind and one for the default image.

If your program already has one selected for a particular user, for example stored in some sort of local storage / database, it can call the first method, however if an image is not found it can call the default no parameter method.

Comment: it cannot read the default image because of the parameters string in loadImage. the error was Can't read input file. Cannot convert String to File

Comment: have you checked the URI? you have two \ in there, was that intended? You also have three ... and no slash?

Comment: Can you explain what the path is meant to be doing then? When you say it's correct, it obviously isn't as it can't find the file.  Have you tried an absolute path instead to see if it can find the image?

Comment: I've copied the path from the files properties. also when i tried to run it w/o the 2nd method. it reads the input file..